# Since I installed Ubuntu 18.04, I can't find the shortcut directories

Tags: 18.04, directory, shortcuts, bookmarks

For most people, they have the shortcut directories on the left and it is easy to access. After my installation, I could not find these shortcuts(Home,Desktop,Documents,Downloads,Music,etc...). This is my second installation, the first one worked fine, I could see them, but with this second installation, I can't find these shortcuts and it makes navigation a little hard

[image]

This is how my Folder directory looks like
[image]

. There are not shortcuts for easy access. Please how can I solve this?